# Tensorflow and OpenCV real-time classification

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow, inception

I am testing the machine learning waters and used [TS inception](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#4) model to retrain the network to classify my desired objects.

Initially, my predictions were run on locally stored images and I realized that it took anywhere between 2-5 seconds to unpersist the graph from a file and around the same time to run the actual predictions.

Thereafter, I adapted my code to incorporate the camera feed from OpenCV but with the above noted times, video lags are inevitable.

A time hit was expected during initial graph load; which is why `initialSetup()` is ran beforehand, but 2-5 seconds is just absurd.
I feel like with my current application; real-time classification, this is not the best way of loading it. Is there another way of doing this? I know with mobile versions TS recommends trimming down the graph. Would slimming it down be the way to go here? In case it matters my graph is currently 87.4MB

Along with this, is there a way of speeding up the prediction process?

```
import os
import cv2
import timeit
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile('retrained_labels.txt')]

def grabVideoFeed():
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    return frame if grabbed else None

def initialSetup():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    print 'Took {} seconds to unpersist the graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

def classify(image_data):
    print '********* Session Start *********'

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        print 'Tensor', softmax_tensor

        print 'Took {} seconds to feed data to graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # This takes 2-5 seconds as well
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': image_data})

        print 'Took {} seconds to perform prediction'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        print 'Took {} seconds to sort the predictions'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        print '********* Session Ended *********'

initialSetup()

while True:
    frame = grabVideoFeed()

    if frame is None:
        raise SystemError('Issue grabbing the frame')

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # adhere to TS graph input structure
    numpy_frame = np.asarray(frame)
    numpy_frame = cv2.normalize(numpy_frame.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    numpy_final = np.expand_dims(numpy_frame, axis=0)

    classify(numpy_final)

    cv2.imshow('Main', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**EDIT 1**

After debugging my code, I realized that session creation is a both resource and time consuming operation.

In the prior code, a new session was created for each OpenCV feed on top of running the predictions.
Wrapping the OpenCV operations inside a single session provides a massive time improvement but this still adds a massive overhead on the initial run; prediction takes 2-3 seconds. Afterwards, the prediction takes around 0.5s which makes the camera feed still laggy.

```
import os
import cv2
import timeit
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile('retrained_labels.txt')]

def grabVideoFeed():
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()
    return frame if grabbed else None

def initialSetup():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # This takes 2-5 seconds to run
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    print 'Took {} seconds to unpersist the graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

initialSetup()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    print 'Took {} seconds to feed data to graph'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

    while True:
        frame = grabVideoFeed()

        if frame is None:
            raise SystemError('Issue grabbing the frame')

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        cv2.imshow('Main', frame)

        # adhere to TS graph input structure
        numpy_frame = np.asarray(frame)
        numpy_frame = cv2.normalize(numpy_frame.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        numpy_final = np.expand_dims(numpy_frame, axis=0)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # This takes 2-5 seconds as well
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': numpy_final})

        print 'Took {} seconds to perform prediction'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()

        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        print 'Took {} seconds to sort the predictions'.format(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        print '********* Session Ended *********'

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            sess.close()
            break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**EDIT 2**

After fiddling around, I stumbled into [graph quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization) and [graph transformation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms) and these were the attained results.

Original Graph: 87.4MB

Quantized Graph: 87.5MB

Transformed Graph: 87.1MB

Eight Bit Calculation: 22MB but ran into [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10739) upon use.

Comment: Are you running on a machine with s gpu?

Comment: what's *s gpu*? Assuming u meant *a gpu*, I installed TS but w/out GPU support because the end goal is to port the model over to a phone.

Answer (score 2):

I have my own project that works similarly (but much simpler model), and it takes me about 0.1s to run my predictions in real time. You did the right thing by re-using the session -- that's what I did too. My guess is that your bottleneck is the size of the model. As far as I'm aware, the Inception model is huge. There will always be a tradeoff between model complexity and runtime prediction speed. The Inception model is accurate, but no one ever said it was fast.

Comment: Thanks alot.. With your case, did your initial prediction take as long as it did mine? The moment I ran my code, the very first prediction still takes a long time and thereafter it goes down to 0.5s.

Comment: I didn't measure that because in my case (self driving toy car) I wouldn't tell the car to move until the model was loaded and ready. If initial startup time is important to you, then it would probably be easier to simply start the program well in advance of when you need to consume its predictions.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that hardware matters a lot for complex calculations like this. I originally had my code running on a Raspberry Pi, and it took 0.3-0.5s. Running it on my laptop instead and sending the results over the network (+0.04s) added a comparatively small amount of latency but made the actual prediction calculation 3-5x faster overall.

Comment: I sincerely do appreciate your help... I still have a few questions pertaining the methods you used to speed up your prediction. Would you mind continuing this conver in a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60936/helloworld)?